# Integral equation solution (Fredholm, second type)

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, integral-equations

There is an equation
$$
w(x) = g(x)+\int\limits_0^M w(y)f(x-y)\,dy
$$
where $f\geq 0$, $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R\setminus\{c\})$ for some point $c$ and $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt\leq 1$. With regards to $g$ we know that $0\leq g(t)\leq 1$. This equation should be solved for $w(x)$ on $[0,M]$. Functions $g,f$ are given. I also know a priori that $w\in C([0,M])$ and bounded by $0$ and $1$.

I guess that it is impossible to solve it analytically. For the numerical methods
I know just one method - Neumann series, moreover $$\sup\limits_{x\in[0,M]}\,\,\,\,\,\,\int\limits_0^M f(x-y)dy = \alpha<1$$
but $1-\alpha\approx 0.001$ so the convergence of these series is very slow. Could you advise me any other method for the solution of this problem - or maybe you can refer me to the appropriate literature?

*Edited:* Thanks to Paul's comment I made my question more explicit. Unknown is function $w$ on $[0,M]$ rather than the point $x$. I would like to stress that the solution I need must be $\varepsilon$-precise, i.e. $\|w-w^*\|\leq \varepsilon$ for the numerical solution $w^*$ . Here $\|\cdot\|$ is a sup-norm.

I also posted this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70880/integral-fredholm-equation-of-the-second-type).

Comment: If it truly is $x$ to be found, it is not accurate to say that this is a Fredholm equation, ... as the latter would solve for an unknown function (e.g., for your $w$ above, given $g$ and $f$). Is the question really posed as intended?

Comment: @paul garrett: thank you, it is indeed an equation on $w$ - now I edited to make this fact more explicit.

Comment: Would a direct discretization of the integral (leading 
to a system of linear equations on $w(x_i)$) work here?

Comment: @Andrew: maybe it would. I only wonder what will be the error in this case. Perhaps, I should also mention in the question that the solution I need must be $\varepsilon$-precise.

Comment: Probably an answer would be just too long. I recommend to start with the book "Theory of Tikhonov Regularization for Fredholm Equations of the First Kind" by Groetsch. This should help in understanding if (or if not) you have an ill-posed problem. There should also be pointers to numerical methods there. You could consider CG here...

Comment: What do you mean with ill-posedness? The solution is unique, unfortunately the convergence is too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in the case someone will be interested in a problem of such a kind. Very nice methods are developed by Prof. Kendall E. Atkinson. I read some of his papers and also used his toolbox for MATLAB which solves these problems very precise. One can find the description of a toolbox [here](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/ftp/Fie_paper.pdf) and code [here](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/fred.html).